# What is the duration of chords shown on top of a measure

Tags: chords, notation, sheet-music, sight-reading

In the image, there is an A Major over the first measure. Should it be also played over the 2nd, 3rd and 4th measures even though the chord is not written on top? Until the D chord in the 5th measure?

[image: Eight measures with some chord symbols]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the A chord applies to all of the measures until the next chord indication. That chord in turn (the D) lasts until another different chord is given.

Answer (score 4):

There's no point in repeating the chord symbol if the chord remains the same. Only when it changes is it necessary to indicate the new chord. Which won't have its symbol repeated, but that will continue, bar by bar, until a different chord is needed. Hence the next A, after which it keeps getting played until...the next change. (Which I'm guessing will be E).

Comment: It is E indeed!

Comment: An excellent deduction Mr. Holmes!

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - I do me best. Sometimes it works..!